# C having trouble in using kernel linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to use this file, [list.h](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/list.h), in my flights info system program.

But, my program seems had some trouble when I was tried to link the new node to the first node of the linked list.

Here is my code

```
#include somefiles balabala


typedef struct flight {
        char ID[10];
        char departure[20];
        char arrival[20];
        char dep_date[8];
        char dep_time[4];
        char arr_time[4];
        float price;
        struct list_head list;
} flight;

typedef struct node {
        flight info;
        struct list_head list;
} flight_node, *p_flight;

p_flight init_list () {
        p_flight head = malloc (sizeof (flight_node));
        INIT_LIST_HEAD (&(head->list));
        return head;
}

void add_flight (p_flight node) {
        p_flight new_node;
        new_node = malloc (sizeof(flight_node));

        system ("clear");
        printf (" \e[1;36m>\33[0m Importing new flight info:\n");
        printf (" Please input the \e[1;33mID\33[0m of the filght: ");
        scanf ("%s", new_node->info.ID);
        printf (" Please input the \e[1;33mdeparture\33[0m of the filght: ");
        scanf ("%s", new_node->info.departure);
        printf (" Please input the \e[1;33marrival\33[0m of the filght: ");
        scanf ("%s", new_node->info.arrival);
        printf (" Please input the \e[1;33mdeparture date\33[0m of the filght: ");
        scanf ("%s", new_node->info.dep_date);
        printf (" Please input the \e[1;33mdeparture time\33[0m of the filght: ");
        scanf ("%s", new_node->info.dep_time);
        printf (" Please input the \e[1;33marrival time\33[0m of the filght: ");
        scanf ("%s", new_node->info.arr_time);
        printf (" Please input the \e[1;33mprice\33[0m of the filght: ");
        scanf ("%f", new_node->info.price);
        list_add (&(new_node->list), &(node->list));    // Seems the problem will have a **segment fault** here
}

int main (void) {
        p_flight list = init_list();
        add_flight (list);
        return 0;
}
```

I am not sure what cause this.
Is that I access the memory **new_node->list** causing this or anything else?

Thank you!

Comment: `scanf ("%f", new_node->info.price);` invokes *undefined behavior* for passing data having incorrect type and have a big chance to crash in typical environment.

Comment: @MikeCAT Isn't that **new_node->info.price** an address? I am confused, when I passing values like **char** type, it is an address, but not **float**? And what if I defined the `price` like this `float *price`, can it work when I try to passing data when I using `scanf ("%f", new_node->info.price)` ?

Comment: `new_node->info.price` has type `float`, and it is definitely not an address.

Comment: `char` is definitely not an address, either.

Comment: Changing to `float *price` should work if you allocate enough buffer and store its address to `new_node->info.price` before calling `scanf ("%f", new_node->info.price)`.